# How to determine cause of sudden recurring daily spike in "Load" not correlated with usage?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

A few days ago (after March 19th~25th-ish), the "Load" statistic for our Database/Project started increasing above it's long term average (which it sat at for the preceding days with no significant spikes). On Monday April 1st, however, it became severe and our app (web-app, Angular) is effectively dead-watered for hours, approx 6:00am to 11:00am Pacific Time.  That day, Firebase Status reported an outage #19009: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Realtime%20Database/19009
Problem is that this recurred for us on Tue, Wed, and Today, each time with, best we can tell, the exact same symptoms, even though no additional Firebase Outages have been reported.

**The fact that Firebase Status reported an official Outage on Monday April 1st during this exact same daily time window is unlikely to be a coincidence.**

*We have Gold Level GC support, but have been now told there is no "phone support" available for Firebase, and support response has done nothing but ask for Profiler output.*

I super appreciate your suggestions, including any possible escalation paths, consultants, etc.. We have *_not_* had a sudden growth spike in users or activity (unless a new user is doing something untoward). Of course, inflection points are possible - we have steady ***linear*** growth.

Working with Firebase Database email based support on a daily basis. Sending requested Profiler reports (but since problem seems to clear around 1100h PT daily, they may not be getting to the issue during the critical peak time).

Comment: *firebaser here* It is unlikely that anyone outside of support can do anything without seeing a way to reproduce the problem, which seems unlikely given your description. Going through support (either the free support [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/) or through your existing paid GCP support account) is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. They moved us to a different server this afternoon (even after continuing to insist that the problem is our application and not Firebase's infrastructure). The new server has more headroom.

I guess we will find out tomorrow (Friday) morning whether or not the "Load" usage on the new server replicates the pattern of the old server (and possibly even uses up the extra headroom), or if our "Load" is back to normal (thus indicating that the problem was/is with the original _**server**_ and _not_ our application.